# Scala 2.9 can't run "hello world" sample on Windows XP

Tags: windows, scala

I'm trying to run HelloWorld sample with scala 2.9.1 final on Windows XP:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, World!")
}
```

File is saved as `Hello.scala`.

When I run `scalac Hello.scala`, it's ok.

When I run `scala Hello`, it writes:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target"
```

It's ridiculous, my `echo %PATH%` contains:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib;
C:\Program Files\scala\bin
```

so everything seems to be in classpath.

Running `scala -classpath "%PATH%;." Hello` doesn't help either.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `scala HelloWorld`?

I can repro your problem on Mac too:

```
$ scalac hello.scala 
$ scala HelloWorld
Hello, World!
$ scala Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: Hello
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:109)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:17)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

`scala` expects either a class name or a source name. `scala Hello` doesn't resolve to either of them.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter how'd you name the file. I got it. Well, hm. maybe I've missed something.

Comment: I think you're right. Because there seems to be no files Hello.class or  smth like that had being created after the compilation. But there is another 'problem', if run without compilation, I mean `scala hello.scala` it doesn't report any problems but it also doesn't print 'hello world' - that's strange.

Comment: If you run `scala hello.scala` the interpreter will define the Object, but not automatically invoke it.

Answer (score -2):

I think it´s a `CLASSPATH` issue. You could try this:

```
$ scala -classpath . Hello
```

Comment: This question was already answered, and the asker specifically ruled out a classpath issue...