# Scala on Mac - Cannot figure out how to run target?

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to run a Scala script that imports `scala.IO.Source`, which throws an exception every time I try to run it as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: countchars1.scala
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:17)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

I believe it is due to my Path or Classpath settings but I'm unsure what these need to be or where they need to be set. I have tried amending `.bash_profile` to no avail and have tried adding `.profile` with what I believe to be the required `PATH` settings but there doesn't appear to be a straight answer to this that I can find

I'm currently running Scala 2.9.1 on a Mac OSX 10.6. The script I'm trying to run from 'Programming in Scala' is as follows:

```
import scala.io.Source

if (args.length > 0) {
  for (line <- Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines)
print(line.length +" "+ line)
}
else
Console.err.println("Please enter filename")
```

I encounter the exception when I type the following in the terminal window:

```
$ scala countchars1.scala countchars1.scala
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What command exactly are you typing to run it? Can you show us what is in your `countchars1.scala` file? Which version of Scala and which Java runtime environment version do you have?

Comment: As Jesper commented, more information would be helpful. In absence, the answer to this question may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622626/scala-2-9-cant-run-hello-world-sample-on-windows-xp

Comment: Just edited the question to include the additional details as requested. I seem to have Java SE 6 installed.

Comment: It's just a CLASSPATH problem. Can you check your classpath, or post it here? Where did you extracted scala?

Comment: I used the homebrew installation method at first to install Scala. How do i check my CLASSPATH? When I type 'echo CLASSPATH' nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue by setting the JAVA_HOME variable using the following instructions:

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/how-to-set-the-java_home-variable-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/